# Prevent Networkx graphs in spring layout from having a rectangular constraint

Tags: python, networkx

How do I change the 'shape' that networkx's spring layout restricts the networks to? At the moment, all of my outputs have an obvious rectangular constraint, e.g.

[image]

this one was crated with the code:

```
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G,k=0.15,iterations=20)
    nx.draw(G, pos)
```

I'd ideally like there to be either no obvious boundary, or a circular boundary rather than rectangle.

Comment: I've never seen it do this before.  Could it be something about using iterations=20 (I think the default is 50).

Comment: Something isn't working right.   Could you post a complete example code?

Comment: @Aric - yes, turned out here was a problem elsewhere - specifically, I was looping over networks, but not clearing the plots each time... so new network was getting put on top of the old one. Not sure why that was causing it to spread out the margins of the rectangle, but possibly because it meant it was iterating 20 more times for every loop.